# using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Developer Machine 32 bit - SQL Server 64 bit

Tags: c#, sql-server, clickonce, smo

I develop a Windows Forms Application on a 32 bit Win7 machine and have a SQL Server 2008 on the same machine for testing. The database server of the release inviroment has 64 bit. When I install the application on a client (32 bit) in the release inviroment which is connected with the 64 bit SQL Server I get the following failure when my code try to use SQL Server Management Objects (SMO):

Code which causes the failure:

```
        private static bool createDatabase(string dbName, string sqlPath, string connStr)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(sqlPath + dbName + ".sql");
        string strscript = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
        bool result;
        string test = "CREATE DATABASE [" + dbName + "]";

        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            using (connection)
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(test, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                    result = true;
                }
            }

            if (result == true)
            {
                connStr = connStr + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbName;
                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                ServerConnection svrConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
                Server server = new Server(svrConnection);

                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(strscript); // Here the app crashes
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ae)
        {
            result = false;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ae.Message.ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Failure message:

Anwendung: XingaAdmin.exe
Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319
Beschreibung: Der Prozess wurde aufgrund einer unbehandelten Ausnahme beendet.
Ausnahmeinformationen: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stapel:
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean, Boolean)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, Boolean)
   bei System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.String)
   bei Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetStatements(System.String, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionTypes, Int32 ByRef)
   bei **Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery**(System.String, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionTypes)
   bei XingaCommonClasses.Utilities.Database.DatabaseHelper.createDatabase(System.String, System.String, System.String)
   bei XingaCommonClasses.Utilities.Database.DatabaseHelper.checkDatabase(System.Collections.Generic.List`1, System.String)
   bei XingaAdmin.Program.Main()

The database is created fine, but the sql-script with the table creation is not executed.

Is it possible that I have to use the 64 bit version of the SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)? But if, how can I get this version. I cannot install the 64 bit version on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: Just as a side line, your current method will return true if the CREATE DATABASE command does not fail, as in it doesn't throw any exceptions when it is translated into pure SQL and run on the database. What do you do if the CREATE DATABASE command succeeds but the actual command is wrong? You should check for the existence of the database after that command is run, BEFORE returning true.

Comment: Ok, but I checked on the server that the database was properly created.

Comment: So how does your connStr look like, the one you're passing in as a parameter?

Comment: Data Source=SBS2008\SAGE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=*******;Initial Catalog=********

Comment: If your executable runs on a 32bit machine, it will use the 32bit version of SMO that could connect to a remote 64bit server without problems. I think the problem is inside your script or in the connection string rebuilt after the create database. Could you show something of these parts?

Comment: Also the final exception is a FileNotFound exception. Do you have the `InnerException != null` in your `catch (SqlException ae) `

Comment: if you are passing in that connStr, you are adding an additional "Initial Catalog" entry, which leaves you with double entries

Comment: Additionally, what does the sqlPath parameter contain?

Comment: @Magnus The path to the sql-script-file. I already checked the string strscript. It has the correct sql-script inside. That means that the file was read properly. When I run this script on the server all tables are created properly.

Comment: You are hiding way too much information for us. Be more transparent and put all the info in your question. Also, exactly which line is causing the Exception?

Comment: @Magnus The "Initial Catalog" is added only once. I gave you the final connStr that is passed into the sqlConnection.

Comment: @Magnus I marked the line which causes the exeption and I also marked it in the exception message.

Comment: @Steve I don't understand your question. When I run the code on my developer machine I don't get any exeption. Only when we run it on the production machine (without debugging possibility) we get the problem. The exception message is all what we get.

Comment: Inside the catch block add this `if(ae.InnerException != null) MessageBox(ae.InnerException.Message);`

Comment: @andre, and I asked for what you called your method with, not the final.

Comment: Further, all of your code is dependent on the content of the strscript variable, which you are trying to execute. What does it contain?

Comment: It is a long sql script for creating all tables. If you want I can send it by email.

Comment: Just another idea, could it be a permission problem? FileNotFound is often accompanied to this problem.

Comment: @Steve It could be ... I struggle already 3 days. My idea is either the 32/64 bit question as I asked here or the fact that the SQL Server Management Objects are v2.0.50727 and the other dlls are v4.0.30319. I already included   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup> into the app.config.

Comment: I tend to exclude a problem with the bitness of DLLs because, if it was a problem the exception will be raised at the first usage of an SMO object. I will suggest to use [ProcMon](http://www.sysinternals.com) to watch which file gives the FileNotFound error.

Comment: Ok, I'm presistent and continue to bite, saw a little gem in your tags, see my answer.

Comment: And installing .NET v2, tried that? In any case, do run ProcMon as Steve suggested and look for the FileNotFound error.

Comment: Today I added <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> to the app.config, but I still wait that my client have time to install the new version. With this amendment the installion process should catch the v2 if it is missing. With ProgMon I first must study a while how to do. Take 1-2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080263/microsoft-sqlserver-management-smo-failedoperationexception-backup-failed-for-s) contains the same stack trace, but the stack dump also contains information about which SMO assembly failed to load. Use a try-catch block to dump the stack trace in the exception.

The SQL Server machine needs to have the 64bit SMO library installed.