# 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, smo

I want to take backup and restore database in windows forms application.
SO that data will not be lost.

My code is as following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;


namespace Lodging
{
    class BackupAndRestoreData
    {
        public static void BackupDatabase(string backUpFile)
        {
            ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(@"ANI-PC\MSSQLSERVER");
            Server server = new Server(con);
            Backup source = new Backup();
            source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            source.Database = "db_Lodge";
            BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);
            source.Devices.Add(destination);
            source.SqlBackup(server);
            con.Disconnect();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Backup Successful!!!");
        }

        public static void RestoreDatabase(string backUpFile)
        {
            ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(@"ANI-PC\MSSQLSERVER");
            Server server = new Server(con);
            Restore destination = new Restore();
            destination.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            destination.Database = "db_Lodge";
            BackupDeviceItem source = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);
            destination.Devices.Add(source);
            destination.ReplaceDatabase = true;
            destination.SqlRestore(server);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Restored Successful!!!");
            con.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

When taking backup I am receiving exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
```

**Exception occurs at**

```
source.SqlBackup(server);
```

Can you tell me how to solve this as this is a important task?

Comment: Recursively get all of the inner exceptions. I can all but guarantee that the one at the bottom of the stack will tell you what the actual problem is.

Comment: Your SMO assembly is not installed correctly.See, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080263/microsoft-sqlserver-management-smo-failedoperationexception-backup-failed-for-s